# How to tell which app added a photo to my iCloud Photo Library

Tags: ios, icloud, photos, logs

Today I noticed some photos in my iCloud Photo Library which I did not put there.  I'm not talking about any shared album, this is my personal library. This is alarming since I have never shared my iCloud account or password with anyone, and I use Two-factor authentication for security.

I captured a `sysdiagnose` log and searched it like this for one of the filenames, but this reveals nothing.

```
log show --archive system_logs.logarchive --debug --predicate 'eventMessage contains[cd] IMG_8313"'
```

So how can I tell which application created a particular photo?

Comment: With the edit the question seems to already contain the answer. So if you want to keep the question open, please rephrase it in such a way that it actually still asks a question. You can, if applicable, also post your findings as an answer then.

Comment: I think the title is accurate and it hasn't been answered.  The first paragraph is now just for context, since other users may be in a similar situation.

Comment: It's not about the title but about the content. I've edited the question and removed the answer-like part. It might be useful for others if you add your analysis on this as an answer below.

Comment: @nohillside I always thought Stack Exchange answers have to answer the question completely and correctly, and that partial analysis and suggestions belong as comments instead.  But after re-reading the rules, I guess you're right. Anyway I found the real answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out after some investigation.  Since some apps don't write anything to the log, we have to search the Photos database.  The metadata exists here just as I suspected, in a column called `ZCREATORBUNDLEID`.  To find it, first you need to install the "iCloud Photos for iOS" profile to enable diagnostics from here:
https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/

Then trigger the diagnostic in Settings > Photos > Run Photos Diagnostics.  Airdrop this file to your computer, untar it, and find the database inside called `Photos.sqlite`.  Search like this

```
sqlite3 Photos.sqlite "SELECT ZCREATORBUNDLEID FROM ZADDITIONALASSETATTRIBUTES WHERE ZORIGINALFILENAME = 'IMG_8313.JPG';"
ZCREATORBUNDLEID = com.ifttt.ifttt
```

In this case, it turns out the photo came from an IFTTT applet that I had forgotten about.

Note: This metadata is available only in the iOS database, not in the macOS Photos database.